# How does Kalman filtering work backwards?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, missing-data, data-imputation, kalman-filter

For time series missing value imputation I am using the Kalman filter/smoothing approach, given in the imputeTS package.

As Kalman filter is iterative and needs a view data points to make its estimate calculation work, I am wondering about missing values at the beginning at my time series.
I can see from the results, the function na_kalman does replace those values too.

I have heard that backwards imputation is working too with Kalman. If I want to explain this in simple terms to my costumers, how do I explain this effect?

In my opinion it should be quite easy to achieve backwards filtering, by simply simulating the same process, starting the iteration from the time series endpoint and iterating to its start.

Is my guess right on this? And if I am right, how does na_kalman decide to switch directions? Is there even a way to control this behavior inside the function?